# Django: Apply order by on serialized data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 3 serializers:

```
class abcSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created=Field(source='time')
    result = Field(source='result')

    class Meta:
        model = abc
        fields = ('created','result')
        order_by = ['-created']

class defSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created=Field(source='time')
    result = Field(source='result')
    class Meta:
        model = def
        fields =('created','result')
        order_by = ['-created']



class mainSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    obj1 = abcSerializer()
    obj2 = defSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = main

        fields = ('obj1','obj2')
```

In views.py:

```
data =  main.objects.filter(id=111)
serializer = mainSerializer(data)
return Response(record)
```

In UI I am displaying the serialized data as like below:

```
        created                result
abc     1-9-2016 9:30:00        pass

def     2-9-2016 10:34:00       fail
```

I am getting the serialized data as below:

```
data = [{'created':'1-09-2106','result':'pass'},{'created':'2-09-2106','result':'fail'}]
```

I want to sort the data as per **created field based on latest date**.

```
        created                result
def     2-9-2016 9:30:00        fail
abc     1-9-2016 10:34:00       pass
```

Couldn't figure it out on how to sort on created on created field
 Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Your `order_by = ['-created']` should be inside `class Meta` Fix the indentation

Comment: yes.Thats a mistake.please see updated

Comment: Can someone share some idea what is the fault?

Comment: Wait.. the `Meta` attribute is `ordering` not `order_by`

Answer (score 4):

I think you want the `order` in your model instead of the serializer.

```
class abcModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(...)
    result = ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']
```